# How to get Ember CLI to only recompile SASS when styles change?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm onboarding onto a project built using Ember. The project uses [ember-cli-sass](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass) to watch and compile `.scss` files. The project is fairly large and componentized, with over 100 separate scss files, many of them outside the `/styles` folder, in their respective components folders. As a result, the `ember-cli-build.js` configuration looks like:

```
sassOptions: {
  includePaths: ['app']
}
```

The list is truncated a little bit, but the point is, the project has to include the `/app` path in its list of folders to watch in order to hear all the possible style changes.

This has two side effects. First, it makes for fairly slow SASS compiles. Second, SASS compiles occur when literally any file in the `/app` hierarchy changes, including javascript files.

Is there any way to configure ember-cli or ember-cli-sass to only compile on `.scss` changes?

Comment: Are you able to show a little more code? Are all the .scss file all in the styles folder? Or are there .scss files alongside each component

Comment: They're all in separate folders next to their components. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2):

You should reference your app's many `.scss` files within the primary `app/styles/app.sass` manifest (which follows convention), like this:

```
//    Component SCSS
// -------------------------------------
@import "../components/component-a"
@import "../components/component-b"
@import "../components/component-c"
etc.
```

[Broccoli is configured to look for the app.sass manifest file in `app/styles`](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation#stylesheets), and thus, you would no longer need to set `includePaths`:

```
sassOptions: {},
```

...thereby avoiding a watch of the entire `app` directory tree.

However, if that is prohibitive for whatever reason, given that the `.scss` files are mingled alongside their respective components, you might consider tightening the designated paths for the `includePaths` option to reduce some of the watching:

```
sassOptions: {
  includePaths: [
    'app/components',
    'app/styles',
  ]
}
```

If you are *not* relying on styles also being set via linked NPM modules, you can restrict even further by setting the [`onlyIncluded`](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass#usage) option as well:

```
sassOptions: {
  includePaths: [
    'app/components',
    'app/styles',
  ],
  onlyIncluded: true
}
```

Setting the `onlyIncluded` option "helps with performance when using NPM linked modules".